# android - Update new data only in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have 500 above records in the list and i am using pagination to load 10 records each time, animation applied to the recyclerview what i want to do is when i am using `notifyDataChanged` its refresh all items of recyclerview, due to this reason my applied animation not working properly as i want.

Any idea how to refresh only new data in the recyclerview so that all items of recyclerview will not change.

Comment: use `adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged()` method.

Comment: i used but its reload old items aslo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method to update only newly added data in `adapter`,

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount);
```

or use

```
adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount);
```

> here,
>
> **positionStart:** is a starting position from where you've inserted data (list size for most cases when inserted at end of list)
>
> **itemCount:** is number of items inserted to list
>
> More from [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyitemrangechanged)

---

**notifyItemRangeInserted**

Notify any registered observers that the currently reflected `itemCount` items starting at `positionStart` have been newly inserted. The items previously located at `positionStart` and beyond can now be found starting at position `positionStart + itemCount`.

This is a structural change event. Representations of other existing items in the data set are still considered up to date and will not be rebound, though their positions may be altered.

> **positionStart:** Position of the first item that was inserted
>
> **itemCount:** Number of items inserted

---

**notifyItemRangeChanged**

Notify any registered observers that the `itemCount` items starting at position `positionStart` have changed. Equivalent to calling **`notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemCount, null);`**.

This is an item change event, not a structural change event. It indicates that any reflection of the data in the given position range is out of date and should be updated. The items in the given range retain the same identity.

> **positionStart:** Position of the first item that has changed
>
> **itemCount:** Number of items that have changed

---

*Different is that **`notifyItemRangeInserted`** treats old data as up to date*

Comment: What is the deffrence between notifyItemRangeInserted and notifyItemRangeChanged which one i should use?

Comment: You should use `notifyItemRangeInserted`, because you're inserting items

Comment: and whats about 'notifyItemRangeInserted' ?

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan check it now.

Answer (score 1):

Use `notifyItemRangeChanged()` method, like if you have 10 items already and when you scroll down 10 new items added to the array then you should do:

```
notifyItemRangeChanged(10,array.size())
```

Which is : `notifyItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount)`

You should use `notifyItemRangeChanged` because it reset items only between given range. rather than `notifyDataSetChanged` which reset all the items of `RecyclerView`.

Comment: I am getting unnecessary gape between items when i used notifyItemRangeChanged.

Comment: Make sure in design of your recycler view  item, root view should have height = "wrap_content"

Comment: Its "wrap_content" already still facing same problem. its happing with first record of recyclerview only.

Comment: also check recycler view height it should be wrap content

Comment: If this not solved your problem then please add xml file code in question and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by specifying on which position you inserted the new data by calling

[RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyItemInserted(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemInserted(int))

Answer (score 0):

you can use DiffUtil to refresh particular item changes.
for reference check this https://proandroiddev.com/diffutil-is-a-must-797502bc1149